# Using scope variables with non-form elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

If I have 2 divs (removed ng-click function for simplicity)

```
<div ng-class="{selected: header.type == 'percent'}" data-type="percent"></div>
<div ng-class="{selected: header.type == 'invisible'}" data-type="invisible"></div>
```

This will apply the class of .selected to one of the divs, depending on the value of $scope.header.type

However, I also have it so when I click on the div that does not have the .selected class, i remove the selected class from the div that had it, and apply it to the div that was just clicked.

Now, on the controller, how do I get the data-type of the div that has the .selected class?

Basically I'm trying to set $scope.header.type to hold the value of data-type of the div that has the .selected class

Just in case it's needed, here's the ng-click fn (which is not angular-like, but I couldn't find an alternative)

```
$scope.changeOfferbox = function($event) {
    var selected  = angular.element(document.querySelector('.selected'))
    selected.removeClass('selected')
    var clicked = angular.element($event.target).addClass('selected')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution might be to pass the data-type to your click function ; this way, you actually don't even need to manually add/remove classes, the ng-class directives will automatically update when header.type changes :

```
$scope.changeOfferbox = function($event, localType) {
    if (localType !== $scope.header.type) {
        $scope.header.type = localType;
    }
};

<div ng-class="{selected: header.type == 'invisible'}" ng-click="changeOfferbox('invisible');" data-type="invisible"></div>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (localType would pass as undefined). Ended up using ng-click="changeOfferbox($event.target)", and inside the ng-click fn, i grab data-type with var type = element.attributes['data-type'].value

Comment: I forgot $event in the call, sorry. Glad you worked it out anyway !